# Do Sunni Muslims consider the musnad of Imam Ahmad as equal to the six canonical hadith collections?

Tags: hadith, sunni, uloom-al-hadith

Do Sunni Muslims consider the musnad of `Imam Ahmad` as equal to the six canonical hadith collections (i.e. `Saheeh Muslim, Saheeh Bukhari, Jami'at al-Tirmidhi, Muwatta Malik, Sunan Abi Dawood and Sunan An-Nisai'`)?

Comment: "Equal" in what way?  Obviously it's not considered one of the six canonical hadith collections insofar as you're clearly aware of all six of them already.  Beyond that, what exactly do the other six have in common that you're even trying to compare?